# Relationship between fourier transform and fourier series

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-series, amplitude

Let
$$x(t) = A\sin(2 \pi f_0 t + \alpha)$$
its Fourier transform is given by $$ X(\omega) = \frac{A \pi}{i}(e^{ia}\delta(\omega-2\pi f_0) - e^{-ia}\delta(w+2\pi f_0)). $$
the Fourier series complex representation of a $T$-periodic is :
$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{(2 i \pi n)/T \cdot t}$$ thus its Fourier transform is $X(\omega) =2 \pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \delta(\omega - 2 \pi n/T)$
now here is my question, whats the expression of $c_n$ by identification with the first Fourier transform of the first signal previously, here is what i did : since $\exists k = \omega \cdot T/(2 \pi)$ then the Fourier transform becomes
$$X(\omega) = 2 \pi c_k = \frac{A \pi}{i}(e^{ia}\delta(\omega-2\pi f_0) - e^{-ia}\delta(w+2\pi f_0))  \iff \begin{align} c_k = \frac{A}{2i}(e^{ia}\delta(\omega-2\pi f_0) - e^{-ia}\delta(w+2\pi f_0)) \end{align}$$
is this valid? if not whats the problem? if it is then how can i determine the amplitude and frequency spectrum of this signal?

Comment: Look at all them $2\pi$ factors floating around in there.  No better example for why we should be using ordinary frequency, $f$, rather than angular frequency, $\omega$ in the Fourier Transform.  It put's the $2\pi$ where it belongs.  In the exponent.

Comment: i really dont understand the hint or the point you trying to transmit , can you elaborate more ? @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: As you've shown yourself, the coefficients $c_k$ are the *weights* of the Dirac impulses, so how can they themselves be Dirac impulses? And where is the index $k$ in your expression for $c_k$? You really just need to equate the Fourier transform of the sinusoid with the Fourier transform of a periodic signal in terms of $c_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform looks right, but the logic afterwards needs some correction.

$$
X(\omega) = 
-i \pi  A \left(e^{i \alpha } \delta \left(\omega -2 \pi  f_0\right)-e^{-i \alpha } \delta \left(2 \pi  f_0+\omega
   \right)\right)
$$
you made a slight mistake with this equality:
$$
X(\omega) = 2 \pi \sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} c_n \delta ( \omega - 2 \pi n f_0 ) = 2 \pi \sum^{1}_{n=-1} c_n \delta ( \omega - 2 \pi n f_0 )
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
X(\omega) 
= 2 \pi c_{-1} \delta(\omega - 2 \pi (-1) f_0) + 0 + 2 \pi c_{1} \delta(\omega - 2 \pi (1) f_0) 
= \pi \left(2 c_{-1} \delta(\omega + 2 \pi f_0) + 2c_{1} \delta(\omega - 2 \pi f_0) \right)
$$
so we can equate to our original Fourier Transform
$$
\pi \left(
2 c_{-1} \delta(\omega + 2 \pi f_0) + 2c_{1} \delta(\omega - 2 \pi f_0) \right) 
= 
-i \pi  A \left(
e^{i \alpha } \delta \left(\omega -2 \pi  f_0\right)-e^{-i \alpha } \delta \left(2 \pi  f_0+\omega
   \right)\right)
$$
$$
\pi \left(2 c_{-1} \delta(\omega + 2 \pi f_0) + 2c_{1} \delta(\omega - 2 \pi f_0) \right) 
=
\pi \left(
-i A e^{i \alpha } \delta \left(\omega -2 \pi  f_0\right)
+ i A e^{-i \alpha } \delta \left(2 \pi  f_0+\omega
   \right)
\right)
$$
so by inspection then
$$
c_{-1} = \frac{i A e^{-i \alpha}}{2}  \qquad c_1= \frac{-iAe^{-i \alpha}}{2}.
$$
Just note that depending how you define your Fourier Transform (there are a few conventions) your coefficients can change.